# Unity: Interactive menu with sprites changing with buttons

Tags: unity, menu

I have a menu where the player gets to choose which team and kit he will use to play. However I don't really know how to change the sprite each time the left or right arrows are pressed. I already have the sprites for each team, league and kit the only thing I am missing is the way to arrange it via script. 
Thanks.

[image: Team selection menu, the arrows display the image of the league, team and kit the player can choose to play with.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all sprites in a array and have a index for selected team for example something like this:

```
List<Sprite> Slist;
int Index = 0;
if(user press next)
    flagObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Slist[Index++];
if(user press previous)
    flagObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Slist[Index--];
```

Although you should check for Index to not going out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Unity UI's Scroll rect. Trick is to use a mask so that only one element can be displayed at a time. Refer [Scroll Rect](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/ui-scroll-rect)